# How do I get \chaptername to appear in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, tocloft

In my tex file I have changed the chapter name from 'Chapter' to 'Day', using:

```
\renewcommand \chaptername {Day}
```

But when I generate a table of contents it only shows '1' and not 'Day 1'. How do I get the 'Day' to show up in the contents?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I recommend using the `tocloft` package, although I suspect the `titletoc` package could also be used quite easily. `tocloft` provides many hooks for content to be inserted into the table of contents.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft,calc}
\renewcommand\chaptername{Day}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername\space}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\widthof{\textbf{Day~999~}}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{500}
\chapter{Hello}
\end{document}
```

In this case `\cftchappresnum` inserts its argument in the `chap` entry, `pre` (before) the `snum` (sectioning number).

As mentioned by Juan (thanks!), it's also necessary to increase the size of the space allocated for the "chapter number". In this case we calculate how large **Day 999** would be (using the calc package) and use that length.

Comment: In the above example you also need something like `\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{1.4cm}` to increase the space available to typeset “Day n”.

Comment: @Juan: I guess you should be the answering, and not me `:)`

Comment: This works for me when I copy your example, but I was using the Memoir class for my file, and when I try it in that I get this error:

! LaTeX Error: \cftchappresnum undefined.

Comment: Why does it change the font size of table of content title? How can I resize it with my custom value.

Comment: Sorry, problem has been solved. I should use `title` option along with `tocloft` package if I want to use my custom title. Anyway, thank you for this solution.

Answer (score 5):

Woo, answering my own question!

I probably should have mentioned it was Memoir class in the first place.
Anyway, after some investigating, I worked out that I had to add the line:

```
\renewcommand*{\cftchaptername}{Day\space}
```

Which did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use {polyglossia}, you would change the chaptername with

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\addto\captionsenglish{%
 \renewcommand\chaptername{%
Day}}
```

(also works for german, replacing the corresponding strings... respectively)

see also: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=788