# Appendix with own toc

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I want to have two table of contents in my document. The first (main) shall only contains "Appendix A: ...", "Appendix B: ..." and so on with page numbers.
In the appendix I want another table of contents which tells me, what sections are available and on which page.

I have searched in the internet, but I couldn't find any thing matching.
I think I am not the first person trying that with LaTeX.

What is the best way to start?

**EDIT:**
I used now the solution from lockstep with the additional `\phantomsection` ([Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9138/creating-a-separate-list-of-appendices-with-tocloft/9201#9201)).
Now I am searching for

> ... a possibility to put *Heading on Level 1* under *Appendix*?  [image: the current situation]

I think there must be a separation between the toc and the bookmarks.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9138/510) question may also be helpful.

Comment: @lockstep Thanks for your comment, I have found the original post a few days ago, but I don't get it running for me. Your solutions works fine, but is there a possibility to put *Heading on Level 1* under *Appendix*? (Picture: http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/593/appendixp.jpg)

Comment: @H3llGhost It seems I may have misunderstood your request. If my answer is irrelevant to the question, I'll delete it.

Comment: @Alan It seems, that your toc only shows the chapter. I want the chapters and sections and additional the point appendix but nothing from the appendices in the main toc. This is the reason why I want another toc only for the appendices. (Picture: http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/8079/tocx.jpg)

Comment: Please make sure that all images are uploaded using the official stackexchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: CTRL+G). This ensures that all images are always accessible and do not expire.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can work with `bookmarksdepth`

```
\documentclass[toc=flat,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\maintoc}{%
  \begingroup
    \@fileswfalse
    \renewcommand*{\appendixattoc}{%
      \value{tocdepth}=-10000%
    }%
    \tableofcontents%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\appendixtoc}{
  \begingroup
    \edef\@alltocdepth{\the\value{tocdepth}}%
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{-10000}%
    \renewcommand*{\contentsname}{%
      List of Appendices}%
    \renewcommand*{\appendixattoc}{%
      \setcounter{tocdepth}{\@alltocdepth}%
    }%
    \tableofcontents%
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{\@alltocdepth}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\appendixattoc}{}%
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \clearpage%
  \phantomsection%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\appendixname}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\appendixattoc}%
  \renewcommand*{\thesection}{Appendix~\Alph{section}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maintoc
\blinddocument

\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=-1}
\appendix
\pdfbookmark[-1]{Appendix}{appendixentry}
\appendixtoc
\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=4}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

You can also modify the interna of the level -- here I changed them in the following way:

```
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \clearpage%
  \phantomsection%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\appendixname}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\appendixattoc}%
  \renewcommand*{\thesection}{Appendix~\Alph{section}}%
  \def\toclevel@chapter{1}%0
  \def\toclevel@section{2}%1
  \def\toclevel@subsection{3}%2
  \def\toclevel@subsubsection{4}%
  \def\toclevel@paragraph{5}%
  \def\toclevel@subparagraph{6}%
  \def\toclevel@figure{7}%
  \def\toclevel@table{8}%
}
```

The result is the same:

```
\documentclass[toc=flat,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\maintoc}{%
  \begingroup
    \@fileswfalse
    \renewcommand*{\appendixattoc}{%
      \value{tocdepth}=-10000%
    }%
    \tableofcontents%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\appendixtoc}{
  \begingroup
    \edef\@alltocdepth{\the\value{tocdepth}}%
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{-10000}%
    \renewcommand*{\contentsname}{%
      List of Appendices}%
    \renewcommand*{\appendixattoc}{%
      \setcounter{tocdepth}{\@alltocdepth}%
    }%
    \tableofcontents%
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{\@alltocdepth}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\appendixattoc}{}%
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \clearpage%
  \phantomsection%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\appendixname}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\appendixattoc}%
  \renewcommand*{\thesection}{Appendix~\Alph{section}}%
  \def\toclevel@chapter{1}
  \def\toclevel@section{2}
  \def\toclevel@subsection{3}
  \def\toclevel@subsubsection{4}
  \def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
  \def\toclevel@subparagraph{6}
  \def\toclevel@figure{7}
  \def\toclevel@table{8}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maintoc
\blinddocument

\appendix
\appendixtoc

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Changed the order of `\appendix` and `\pdfbookmark`

Comment: Nearly the expected result, the only thing is that the bookmark doesn't link the page like the other bookmark does it. You can fix it with swapping `\appendix` and `\pdfbookmark[-1]{Appendix}{appendixentry}`.

Comment: It seems, that `\renewcommand*{\thesection}{Appendix~\Alph{section}}%` doesn't work with the class *scrbook*. I have changed it to `\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{Appendix ~\Alph{chapter}}`. I get the "overfull hbox warning".

Answer (score 4):

Here's an option using the `titletoc` package (to build the partial ToCs), the `tocvsec2` package (to control the `tocdepth` for the main Table of Contents), and the `appendix` package (to modify the way appendices appear in the main ToC):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=4}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First regular chapter}
\section{Section one one}
\subsection{Subsection one one one}
\chapter{Second regular chapter}
\section{Section two one}
\subsection{Subsection two one one}

\begin{appendices}
\settocdepth{chapter}
\addtocontents{ptc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
\chapter{First Appendix}
\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{}{1}{}
\section{First section in appendix one}
\subsection{First subsection in appendix one one}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection in appendix one one one}
\section{Second section in appendix one}
\subsection{First subsection in appendix one two}
\stopcontents[sections]
\chapter{Second Appendix}
\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{}{1}{}
\section{First section in appendix two}
\section{Second section in appendix two}
\stopcontents[sections]
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```