# How to get a list of appendices?

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

How to get a list of appendices like the list of figures and list of tables? How
to set it on a separate page, like the list of figures and list of tables?

Comment: There are some related question to mine, I would read them :D first

Comment: Here is the post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24889/appendix-with-own-toc/25402#25402

Comment: You might want to consider accepting the best answer to this and to some of the other questions you've asked. You can do so by clicking on the check mark icon next to the selected answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think that [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24889/appendix-with-own-toc/) is not really the answer to Verly's question, as he doesn't seem to need a TOC for the appendix, merely a list of appendices like list of figures. It's the easiest way to use `tocloft`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{Appendices}
\newlistof{appendices}{apc}{\listappendicesname}
\newcommand{\appendices}[1]{\addcontentsline{apc}{appendices}{#1}}

\parindent0mm

\begin{document}

some text some text some text some text some text some text 

\appendices{appendix one} appendix  appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix

\appendices{appendix two} appendix  appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix

\appendices{appendix three} appendix  appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix

\appendices{appendix four} appendix  appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix

\listofappendices

\end{document}
```

---

**Edit 1:** If you want headings for the appendices, you may do something like this:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{Appendices}
\newlistof{appendices}{apc}{\listappendicesname}
\newcommand{\appendices}[1]{\addcontentsline{apc}{appendices}{#1}}

\newcommand{\newappendix}[1]{\section*{#1}\appendices{#1}}

\parindent0mm

\begin{document}

some text some text some text some text some text some text 
\newappendix{Appendix one} appendix  appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix
\newappendix{Appendix two} appendix  appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix
\newappendix{Appendix three} appendix  appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix
\newappendix{Appendix four} appendix  appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix

\listofappendices

\end{document}
```

This will produce something like this:

[image: Appendices]

---

**Edit 2:** for centered headings do it like this:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{Appendices}
\newlistof{appendices}{apc}{\listappendicesname}
\newcommand{\appendices}[1]{\addcontentsline{apc}{appendices}{#1}}

\newcommand{\newappendix}[1]{\section*{#1}\appendices{#1}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\parindent0mm

\begin{document}

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text  
\newappendix{Appendix one} appendix  appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix 
\newappendix{Appendix two} appendix  appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix 
\newappendix{Appendix three} appendix  appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix 
\newappendix{Appendix four} appendix  appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix 

\listofappendices

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit 3:** For a centered headline for the list of Appendices, change

```
\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{Appendices}
```

simply to

```
\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{\hfill Appendices \hfill}
```

and as we are at it, for aligned right:

```
\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{\hfill Appendices}
```

Comment: How to centering the title of Appendices ?

Comment: sir, that was great answer, but how to centering the title of list appendix ? as to centering toc,lof,lot I do like this :

'\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}'
'\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}'

Comment: adding `\hfill`s before and after the headline will do

Comment: Is it possible to add sections to the appendices? That is, the level being not only the `\newappendix` but also `\section` within `\newappendix`?

Comment: Thank you, this is great!

Comment: When I add `\usepackage{tocloft}` my ToC, list of table, and list of figures all get messed up, and I get a ton of errors.