# List of appendices with tocloft and memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, appendices, tocloft

I found a very nice example showing how to create a list of appendices here: [How to get a list of appendices?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26732/how-to-get-a-list-of-appendices) but it doesn't seem to work with the `memoir` document class.  I get the error message "Command `\appendices` already defined."

How can I create the same list of appendices with the `memoir` class?

Comment: Do you want to remove the appendices as the appear in the regular *Table of Contents* (as chapters) and just have them show up in a *List of Appendices* (with perhaps an entry in the *Table of Contents* pointing to the *List of Appendices*, just like one might have an entry to *List of Tables*)?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one solution using the `memoir` toc code inserts:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
% sample data
\newcounter{dlf}
\newcommand\test{%
  \stepcounter{dlf}
  \chapter{Test chapter \thedlf}
  \section{test section \thedlf}}
\cftinsertcode{preapp}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-10}}
\newcommand\apptoc{
  \begingroup
  \cftinsertcode{prenorm}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-10}}
  \cftinsertcode{preapp}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
  \renewcommand\contentsname{List of appendencies}
  \tableofcontents*
 \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\cftinserthook{toc}{prenorm}

\tableofcontents*

\test\test\test

\appendix
\appendixpage
\cftinserthook{toc}{preapp}

\apptoc

\test\test\test

\end{document}
```

Comment: That seems to nearly do the trick! How would I make it so that there were dots after the appendix entries, and they were not bold?  So that the list of appendices were really like the list of figures?

Answer (score 5):

Memoir already includes tocloft functionality. A minimal example of appendices would be:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{One}
\appendix
\appendixpage
\chapter{Alpha}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See also [memoir manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) section 6.2.1.

Comment: I actually wanted a list of appendices, much like the listoffigures or listoftables.

Isn't it also a bit strange that the page number for the Appendices in your example is 3, when actually Chapter One is on page 3!  Perhaps there is something wrong with \addappheadtotoc?

Comment: My mistake. I should have used `\appendixpage` instead, and it's fixed now. Will work up an example similar to other Lists of X for appendices shortly.