# Separate table of contents for appendices

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, appendices

Is it possible to make two seperate table of contents in one report? I want one for the main document and another for the appendices.

I'm writing in the `memoir` report enviroment.

Comment: Where do you want the second toc in relation to the first one? `Memoir` can do this, though it takes perhaps 5 lines of code.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42548/list-of-appendices-with-tocloft-and-memoir. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: That answer would solve the question.

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

That question sort of answers mine. But I dont want the appendices to show in the first table of content, and I dont want the "normal" content to show in the second table of content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ought to do it. I included the `Appendices` entry in the first toc as I would think this would be better for users.

The idea is to add hooks into the `TOC` file at certain places, such that we can execute code that these places. We then fill in these hooks with code that alter how far down in the toc structure we would like to typeset.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
% just to provide sample code
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\newcounter{tst}
\newcommand\xxx{\stepcounter{tst}\chapter{Test \thetst} \kant[1]}

% disable everything after the POST hook
\cftinsertcode{POST}{
\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}
}

\newcommand\tableofcontentsapps{
\begingroup
% disable first part
\cftinsertcode{PRE}{
\setcounter{tocdepth}{-10}
}
% enable down to subsection within appendices
\cftinsertcode{POST}{
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
}
\renewcommand\contentsname{List of appendices}
\tableofcontents*
\endgroup
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\cftinserthook{toc}{PRE}

\xxx\xxx\xxx

\appendix
\appendixpage

\tableofcontentsapps

\cftinserthook{toc}{POST}

\xxx\xxx\xxx


\end{document}
```