# Separate table of contents for appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, scrbook

We are working on a book (class `scrbook`) where we would like to have two separate table of contents: one at the beginning of the document for the actual "content" of the book and another one just before the first chapter of the appendix starts, which only contains the chapters and sections of the appendix. The appendix itself shall not appear in the main table of contents.
(background: the content of the book will be printed, while the appendix will only be available online as a PDF file)

Something like that:

```
Table of Contents
1   First chapter .... 1
1.1 A section ........ 2

First chapter
text text text

A section
text text text

Appendix
1   Something ....... 5
1.1 Specific ........ 6

Appendix A
Something
text text text

A.1 Specific
text text text
```

I am a bit confused by the possibilities given by different packages like "appendix", "titletoc", "tocloft", ...

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Either it could be done with `KOMA` options, but I am no expert or you give `minitoc` or `etoc` packages a try. Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107506/separate-table-of-contents-for-appendices.  But for sure, that question should provide the details on how to accomplish this.

Comment: @R.Schumacher: It might be, but the KOMA stuff is different to `memoir`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a solution using `etoc` package

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}
\etocdepthtag.toc{mtchapter}
\etocsettagdepth{mtchapter}{subsection}
\etocsettagdepth{mtappendix}{none}
\tableofcontents‎‎
\chapter{First chapter}
text text text

\section{A section}
text text text

\subsection{A subsection}
text text text

\appendix

\etocdepthtag.toc{mtappendix}
\etocsettagdepth{mtchapter}{none}
\etocsettagdepth{mtappendix}{subsection}
\tableofcontents‎‎
\chapter{Appendix A}
text text text

\section{Specific}
text text text

\subsection{A subsection}
text text text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly how it is supposed to be. My Texlive 2012 installation did not contain the etocs package so I upgraded to Texlive 2015. I added another `\etoctocstyle{1}{Appendix Heading}` in order to get the table of contents for the appendix with a dedicated title.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**
Here is a suggestion without any additional package, but it needs KOMA-Script version 3.23 or newer.

```
\documentclass[appendixprefix]{scrbook}[2017/04/13]

\DeclareNewTOC[%
  owner=\jobname,
  listname={\contentsname~(\appendixname)},% title of the appendix ToC
]{atoc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\appendixwithtoc{%
  \appendix
  \renewcommand*{\ext@toc}{atoc}%
  \scr@ifundefinedorrelax{hypersetup}{}{\hypersetup{bookmarkstype=atoc}}%
  \listofatocs
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter I}
\section{Section I}
\chapter{Chapter II}

\appendixwithtoc
\chapter{Annex I}
\section{Section of Annex I}
\chapter{Annex II}
\end{document}
```

---

**Original answer**

Here is another suggestion using the KOMA-Script package `scrwfile`:

```
\documentclass[appendixprefix]{scrbook}
%
\usepackage{scrwfile}
\TOCclone[\contentsname~(\appendixname)]{toc}{atoc}
\newcommand\StartAppendixEntries{}
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{%
  \renewcommand\StartAppendixEntries{\value{tocdepth}=-10000\relax}%
}
\AfterTOCHead[atoc]{%
  \edef\maintocdepth{\the\value{tocdepth}}%
  \value{tocdepth}=-10000\relax%
  \renewcommand\StartAppendixEntries{\value{tocdepth}=\maintocdepth\relax}%
}
\newcommand*\appendixwithtoc{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \appendix
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\StartAppendixEntries}
  \listofatoc
}
%
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter I}
\section{Section I}
\chapter{Chapter II}

\appendixwithtoc
\chapter{Annex I}
\section{Section of Annex I}
\chapter{Annex II}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]