# Separate table of contents for appendix in Beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, appendix

Is there a way to generate a table of contents only listing the sections of the appendix in Beamer?

Essentially I want to do exactly [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260445/separate-table-of-contents-for-appendix), but for a Beamer presentation.
For some reason, the proposed solutions don't work for me. Even just including `etoc` in my beamer document gives loads of error messages (while the sample code provided in the answer of the above question works just fine).

Code example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage{etoc}  % causes errors

\title{Separate TOC for Appendix}
\author{Anonymous}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}{TOC}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section A}
\section{Section B}
\section{Section C}

\appendix

\begin{frame}{Appendix TOC}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Appendix A}
\section{Appendix B}

\end{document}
```

I'd like the second table of contents to list Appendix A and Appendix B.

Comment: Welcome! As soon as I add a frame after `\section{Appendix B}` I get precisely what you are asking for. That is, replace `\section{Appendix B}` by `\section{Appendix B}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some content}

\end{frame}`.

Comment: true, I did not think that would be the default behavior, but seems like exactly what I needed. @Schrödinger'scat if you add this comment as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`beamer` does that automatically. You only need to add some (frame) content after the `\section` commands in the appendix.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage{etoc}  % causes errors

\title{Separate TOC for Appendix}
\author{Anonymous}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}{TOC}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section A}
\section{Section B}
\section{Section C}

\appendix

\begin{frame}{Appendix TOC}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Appendix A}
\section{Appendix B}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Some appendix slide}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]