# Make list of appendices as picture below

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I want to make appendices same as this picture.

[image]

Now I have typed the code as below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=4 cm,right=3cm,top=4cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{ABC}
    \section{First}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \section{Second}
    \lipsum[3-4]
    
    \chapter*{APPENDICES}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
    \titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{Appendix~\thesection.}{1em}{}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{APPENDICES}
        \section{First Appendix}
            \lipsum[4-4]
        
        \section{Second Appendix}
            \lipsum[3-3]
\end{document}
```

Now I want to remove the section of appendices chapter in the table of contents and make the list of appendices same as picture below.

[image]

[image: LIST OF APPENDICES]

I don't know how to make list of appendices. I try to read [How to get a list of appendices?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26732/how-to-get-a-list-of-appendices) and the appearance is not the same with my picture.

My question:

(1) How delete section of appendices chapter in table of contents (as my picture)?

(2) How to make list of appendices and displays on table of contents (as my picture)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tocloft` package helps. Thank you for your MWE (altered below) which saved me time and effort.

```
% appendixlistprob.tex  SE 572170

\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=4 cm,right=3cm,top=4cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{tocloft}
% code for List of Appendices
\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{List of Appendices}
\newlistof{appendix}{app}{\listappendicesname}
% new command for appendix sections
\newcommand{\appsection}[1]{\section{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{app}{appendix}{Appendix \protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}\par}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents

% print list of appendices and add title to the ToC
\listofappendix \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listappendicesname}

    \mainmatter
    \chapter{ABC}
    \section{First}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \section{Second}
    \lipsum[3-4]
    
    \chapter*{APPENDICES}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
    \titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{Appendix~\thesection.}{1em}{}
%%%%%    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{APPENDICES} % don't add to ToC
        \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}} % No sections in ToC
        \appsection{First Appendix}
            \lipsum[4-4]
        
        \appsection{Second Appendix}
            \lipsum[3-3]
\end{document}
```

I think that the above does what you want. I don't know if it could be simpler but you could easily make it more complex.

[image]