# Spacing in list of figures / tables for entries from appendices

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, appendices, tocloft

Having made the changes Werner very helpfully suggested in the [Separate table of appendices - pdf bookmarks & avoid previous chapter's format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39896/separate-table-of-appendices-pdf-bookmarks-avoid-previous-chapters-format), my list is up and running but I have some spacing problems.

I now have an extra space before my figure and table numbers from the appendices. For example, `A.1` in the table of contents. This means it no longer lines up with the lines from the main chapters. In the entry in the `.lot` file there is a space before `{ A.1}`.

[image: Misaglined List of Tables/Figures with entries from appendeices]

Here is the a minimal working example (or at least my best shot at it):

```
\documentclass[]{ut-thesis}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=black]{hyperref}

\begin{document}


\newcommand{\listappendixname}{List of Appendices}
\newlistof{appendix}{app}{\listappendixname}
\setcounter{appdepth}{2}    
\renewcommand{\theappendix}{\Alph{appendix}}
\renewcommand{\cftappendixpresnum}{Appendix\space}
\setlength{\cftbeforeappendixskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\cftappendixnumwidth}{1in}
\newlistentry[appendix]{subappendix}{app}{1}
\renewcommand{\thesubappendix}{\theappendix.\arabic{subappendix}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubappendixpresnum}{Appendix\space}
\setlength{\cftsubappendixnumwidth}{1in}
\setlength{\cftsubappendixindent}{0em}

\newcommand{\myappendix}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{appendix}\pdfbookmark[1]{#1}{#1\theappendix}%
  \chapter*{Appendix \theappendix\space #1}%
  \addcontentsline{app}{appendix}{\protect\numberline{\theappendix}#1}%
  \markboth{}{\MakeUppercase{Appendix}\ \theappendix\space #1}\par
}

\newcommand{\subappendix}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{subappendix}\pdfbookmark[2]{#1}{#1\thesubappendix}%
  \section*{\thesubappendix.\space #1}%
  \addcontentsline{app}{subappendix}{\protect\numberline{\thesubappendix}#1}%
}


\begin{preliminary}

\listoftables
\listoffigures

\end{preliminary}


\chapter{Objective}
\section{Get it done}
\begin{figure}
\caption[Short name for a figure]{Loooong name for the figure with lots of explanation}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption[Short name for my table]{Loooong name for the my  with lots of explanation}
\end{table}

\appendix
\clearpage \phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{ \theappendix.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{ \theappendix.\arabic{figure}}

\myappendix{VBA code for Extension of Jaccard Measure}
\label{chap:code}
\begin{figure}
\caption[Code for functions that do this and that]{}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption[Table showing not very much]{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As your two questions cover two separate matters, please remove one of them from this question and post it as a new question. This way, other users looking for help can find solutions more easily. Also don't forget to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for each question.

Comment: And please use a better title for your questions.

Comment: The [tag:spacing] tag seems to be appropriate for your first question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are spurious blank spaces in the redefinition of `\thefigure` and `\thetable`; use:

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\theappendix.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\theappendix.\arabic{figure}}
```

(in both cases I removed the blank spaces before `\theappendix`).