# Creating a new list of appendices with tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, tocloft

I just implemented Mike Renfro's solution from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9138/creating-a-separate-list-of-appendices-with-tocloft), but the content in the list of appendices also gets listed in the toc, which should not be the case. How would one ensure this is avoided? Below is the code I've used. The `report` class has been used because I want to have chapters in the document.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listappendixname}{List of Appendices}
\newlistof{appendix}{app}{\listappendixname}
\setcounter{appdepth}{2}
\renewcommand{\theappendix}{\Alph{appendix}}
\renewcommand{\cftappendixpresnum}{Appendix\space}
\setlength{\cftbeforeappendixskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\cftappendixnumwidth}{1in}
\newlistentry[appendix]{subappendix}{app}{1}
\renewcommand{\thesubappendix}{\theappendix.\arabic{subappendix}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubappendixpresnum}{Appendix\space}
\setlength{\cftsubappendixnumwidth}{1in}
\setlength{\cftsubappendixindent}{0em}

\renewcommand{\appendix}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{appendix}%
  \chapter{\theappendix\space #1}%
  \addcontentsline{app}{appendix}{\protect\numberline{\theappendix}#1}%
  \par
}

\newcommand{\subappendix}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{subappendix}%
  \section{\thesubappendix\space #1}%sub
  \addcontentsline{app}{subappendix}{\protect\numberline{\thesubappendix}#1}%
}

\usepackage{fmtcount,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\chaptermark}{\thechapter}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\thetocchap}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofappendix

\chapter{Foo} \lipsum[1]
\section{Bar} \lipsum[2]%sub
\chapter{Additional Foo} \lipsum[3]
\section{Additional Bar} \lipsum[4]%sub

\begin{appendices}

\appendix{Baz} \lipsum[5]
\subappendix{Qux} \lipsum[6]
\appendix{Additional Baz} \lipsum[7]
\subappendix{Additional Qux} \lipsum[8]
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now I can officially [Welcome you to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). I would recommend that instead of linking to your _non-answer_ that you link instead to the other question and delete your _non-answer_ at [Creating a separate list of appendices with tocloft](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9138/creating-a-separate-list-of-appendices-with-tocloft/). Also the `@` syntax does not work in questions/answers, only in comments.

Answer (score 4):

Add `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-2}}` in the document body immediately before `\begin{appendices}`. (And don't forget to load the `appendix` package.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{appendix}
\newcommand{\listappendixname}{List of Appendices}
\newlistof{appendix}{app}{\listappendixname}
\setcounter{appdepth}{2}
\renewcommand{\theappendix}{\Alph{appendix}}
\renewcommand{\cftappendixpresnum}{Appendix\space}
\setlength{\cftbeforeappendixskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\cftappendixnumwidth}{1in}
\newlistentry[appendix]{subappendix}{app}{1}
\renewcommand{\thesubappendix}{\theappendix.\arabic{subappendix}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubappendixpresnum}{Appendix\space}
\setlength{\cftsubappendixnumwidth}{1in}
\setlength{\cftsubappendixindent}{0em}

\renewcommand{\appendix}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{appendix}%
  \chapter{\theappendix\space #1}%
  \addcontentsline{app}{appendix}{\protect\numberline{\theappendix}#1}%
  \par
}

\newcommand{\subappendix}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{subappendix}%
  \section{\thesubappendix\space #1}%sub
  \addcontentsline{app}{subappendix}{\protect\numberline{\thesubappendix}#1}%
}

\usepackage{fmtcount,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\chaptermark}{\thechapter}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\thetocchap}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofappendix

\chapter{Foo} \lipsum[1]
\section{Bar} \lipsum[2]%sub
\chapter{Additional Foo} \lipsum[3]
\section{Additional Bar} \lipsum[4]%sub

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-2}}

\begin{appendices}

\appendix{Baz} \lipsum[5]
\subappendix{Qux} \lipsum[6]
\appendix{Additional Baz} \lipsum[7]
\subappendix{Additional Qux} \lipsum[8]
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```