# Separate List of Appendices in new page

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I need to get a separate List of Appendices in a new page, but I get an error

```
Undefined control sequence
```

My code is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\listofappendices

\newpage

\chapter{a1}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\chapter{b1}
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{APPENDICES}
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{MY}
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
\chapter{DFG}
dddddddddddddddd
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please see this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9138/creating-a-separate-list-of-appendices-with-tocloft

Comment: It's not worked.My document class is report and i need to add appendix to table of contents as well as separate list.Can u please check my code and give me a simple solution for this matter..thank u

Comment: There is no `\listofappendices`. Do you need the package `tocloft`?

Answer (score 2):

There is no environment `appendices`. There is a command `appendix` which introduce the appendix.

To get a list of appendix you need a new auxiliary file. In the example below the new auxiliary file gets the extension `toa` (**t** able **o** f **a** ppendix). In the next step you must declare that all entries of the appendix are written to the new file. Therefor I am using the package `xpatch`:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofappendixname{Table of \appendixname}

\newcommand\listofappendices{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listofappendixname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\listofappendixname}{\MakeUppercase\listofappendixname}}%
    \@starttoc{toa}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\appendixname}%
  \xpatchcmd{\@part}{\addcontentsline{toc}}{\addcontentsline{toa}}{}{}%
  \xpatchcmd{\@part}{\addcontentsline{toc}}{\addcontentsline{toa}}{}{}%
  \xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{\addcontentsline{toc}}{\addcontentsline{toa}}{}{}%
  \xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{\addcontentsline{toc}}{\addcontentsline{toa}}{}{}%
  \xpatchcmd{\@sect}{\addcontentsline{toc}}{\addcontentsline{toa}}{}{}%
  \xpatchcmd{\@sect}{\addcontentsline{toc}}{\addcontentsline{toa}}{}{}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\tableofcontents


\listofappendices

\newpage

\chapter{a1}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\chapter{b1}
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb


\appendix

\chapter{MY}
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
\chapter{DFG}
dddddddddddddddd


\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot install the package{xpatch}. I try to search in MikTex package manager(Admin).There is no any package like xpatch.What is a solution for that?

Comment: @Emalka: Which version of MikTeX do you have?

Comment: version 2.8.3761

Comment: @Emalka: As far as I know the current version of MikTeX is 2.9. Maybe you need this version. I am working with TeX Live and the package is part of this. However CTAN tells us that `xpatch` is part of MikTeX: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch

Comment: so,Is there  any solution to get appendix list?thank u very much

Comment: Can I use any otherpackage except xpatch?

Comment: @Emalka Maybe regexpatch. It defines the same commands. However I think you will have the same issue.

Comment: yes ,appear same issue.Anyway thank u very much...

Comment: @Emalka: Without an updated system it's difficult to help you. Sorry.

Comment: @Emalka According to http://miktex.org/releases v2.9 is the current version since October 2010 so your version seems to be quite outdated

Comment: @MarcoDaniel It's ok..