# Add a list of appendices to classicthesis

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, classicthesis

I'm using `classicthesis` for my dissertation. By default the TOC begins with "List of Figures", "List of Tables", and "Listings", as can be seen in the `Contents.tex` source file.

As per university style requirements, I need to add a "List of Appendices" section.

Modeled on the sections above it in `Contents.tex`, I've added the following code to produce a "List of Appendices".

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   List of Appendices
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Appendices}
\pdfbookmark[1]{List of Appendices}{List of Appendices}

\chapter*{List of Appendicies}
Appendix \ref{app:1} Foo \pageref{app:1}\\
Appendix \ref{app:2} Bar \pageref{app:2}\\
Appendix \ref{app:3} Baz \pageref{app:3}\\

\vspace*{8ex}
\newpage
```

But this is inelegant. Is there a way to do this so appendices are automatically picked up and listed, the way figures, tables, and code listings are?

Currently, I declare my appendices in `main.tex` as:

```
\include{Chapters/Chapter0A}
\include{Chapters/Chapter0B}
\include{Chapters/Chapter0C}
...
```

so they are already listed individually in the TOC.

According to the style requirements, the TOC should include a separate "List of Appendices" entry, and below, only display an entry for the beginning of the set of appendices, called "Appendices".  In other words:

> ### TOC
>
> Dedication
>   Acknowledgements
>   Foreword
>   Abstract
>   List of Figures
>   List of Tables
>   List of Appendices
>   Introduction
>   Chapter 1
>   ...
>   Chapter N
>   Conclusion
>   Appendices
>   Bibliography

And the "List of Appendices" section should appear as:

> ### List of Appendices
>
> Appendix A    Foo    X
>   Appendix B    Bar    Y
>   Appendix C    Baz    Z
>   ...

analogously to "List of Figures" say.

Comment: Can you please add to your question a simple mock-up document showing your *current* settings? How are you declaring your appendices? Aren't they already listed in the ToC?

Comment: Thanks @GonzaloMedina. I just edited my original question to clarify.

Comment: Check also this question: [Creating a separate list of appendices with tocloft](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9138/10102)