# How to get the chapter name and other TOC data in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, tocloft

It's a good [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3397/how-do-i-get-chaptername-to-appear-in-the-table-of-contents).
But could you help me to change it a little bit. For example using `report` style in text I wrote:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft,calc}

\renewcommand\chaptername{Introduction}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername\space}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{2cm}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\renewcommand{\thesection}%
{\Roman{section}.}
  \pagenumbering{roman}

\renewcommand\chaptername{Introduction}
 \chapter{Les initiatives}
 \section{Bla bla bla1}
 \section{Bla bla bla2}
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\setcounter{chapter}{0} \setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapter}

\chapter{Les décisions}
```

Could you please tell me how to make the table of content like this:

> Preface..................................i
>
> Introduction. Les initiatives ............v
>
> I.Bla bla bla1..........................vi
>
> II.Bla bla bla2.........................vii
>
> Chapitre 1. Les décisions ................1
>
> 1.1 Bla bla bla3 ........................6
>
> 1.2 Bla bla bla4 ........................7
>
> Chapitre 2. Les conférence ...............10
>
> Conclusion ...............................30
>
> Appendix A ...............................35
>
> Bibliographie ............................40

The code from answer above works fine, but it needs some changes for me, and I can't handle it well. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your request to use "Introduction" as `\chaptername` for one chapter makes things a little bit complicated, but here we go:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername\space}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{2.5cm}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Introduction}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\chaptername{Introduction}}

\chapter{Les initiatives}

\section{Bla bla bla1}
\section{Bla bla bla2}

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapitre}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\chaptername{Chapitre}}

\chapter{Les décisions}

\section{Bla bla bla1}
\section{Bla bla bla2}

\appendix
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\appendixname}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\chaptername{\appendixname}}

\chapter{foo}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

By the way, if you want `\pagenumbering{roman}` for the introductory chapters, you could use the `book` class and its `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` commmands.

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

EDIT Added `\setcounter{section}{0}` in the MWE.

Comment: GREAT!!!! THANK YOU very much. :))) And thank you for advise about book class. I'll try it.