# No page numbers after chapters in the contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

Seems that digging for several hours for solution did not help me, so I must ask a question directly.

So, I'm writing a book, that consists of chapters and sections. The deal is with the table of contents.

I do not want dotted lines and page numbers to follow the chapter name in the table of contents.

But I do want them to follow section names.

Also, how can I make TeX write in contents:

> Chapter 1. This is the first chapter

instead of:

> 1. This is the first chapter

I am using the **book class** with this modification:

```
\addto\captionsrussian{
\def\contentsname{Оглавление}
}

\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\Large\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
```

I saw some decisions, but I do not want to write something before each chapter, how can I define it in my package?

Thank you for assistance =)

P.S. A little question: where can I find a manual for writing TeX styles?

Comment: Wow - three questions in one!  "The LaTeX Companion", Mittlebach, Goosens et al, AW 2004 is pretty good on how to write packages.

Comment: Still, what about those three, they all concern one matter, anyway =)

Comment: I think that the `tocloft` package does all these things....

Comment: See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3397/how-do-i-get-chaptername-to-appear-in-the-table-of-contents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you a lot, Thruston, **tocloft** was really helpfull.

I used the following features of **tocloft**:

```
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername\space}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.\space}
\renewcommand\cftsecaftersnum{.\space}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{1.5cm}
\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}
```